# Git: How to see different of two remote branches?

Tags: git, github

Git: How to see different of two remote branches?

I have two remote branches that I need to check the differents?

Example:

master and develop

of

develop and fix-xyz

what is the git comment to see the files that changes and then to see what lines have changed>?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming I'm reading your question correctly, and assuming they're on `origin`, you can do:

```
git diff remotes/origin/origin remotes/origin/develop
```

and

```
git diff remotes/origin/develop remotes/origin/fix-xyz
```

Comment: I would add that you might want to do a `git fetch` first to make sure that your local repo's idea of where those branches are is accurate...

Answer (score 0):

To compare your local version of develop with the remote version of the develop branch you run

```
git diff develop origin/develop
```

If the branch fix-xyz is branched of master (I found the question a bit unclear, I am assuming this) you can check with

```
git diff fix-xyz origin/master
```

Comment: Ah, yes could be the case. But since there is an "of" between the two examples I assumed that there was a relation between the first set and the second set. That would fit with the git-flow way of branching.